# cannot use ?attr/colorPrimary in drawable android

Tags: android, android-resources

i am try to use shape for background the View but my app crashed.
my code is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<gradient
    android:startColor="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:angle="270" />
</shape>
```

if replace ?attr/colorPrimary with correct color code like #9e9e9e
this code and shape word properly but when i use ?attr/ donot work and force close.how van i fix this problem?

Comment: Try: `android:startColor="?android:attr/colorPrimary"`. If that doesn't work, share your `build.gradle` file and app theme.

Comment: `android:startColor="?android:attr/colorPrimary"`   doesn't work AS IDE say `?android:attr/colorPrimary requires API level 21 (current min is 16)  `how can i share my build.gradle file and app theme.?

Comment: Do you have colorPrimary defined in your colors.xml file?

Comment: yes and i use colorPrimary all around my app